# Database Trigger to verify if the node is leaf or not

Tags: oracle, triggers, tree

I am new to database and I have a requirement. I have a table **Tree** that contain nodes. Table **ConnectedNodes** contain connected nodes

```
CREATE TABLE Tree ( nodeID NUMBER(16,0), parentID NUMBER(16,0))

CREATE TABLE ConnectedNodes (node1 NUMBER(16,0), node2 NUMBER(16,0))
```

Only leaf nodes can be connected. So, I need to write a *Insert/Update* **Trigger** on table **ConnectedNodes** that checks *if both the nodes are leaf node*

I am using Oracle 12c Database.

Below is the trigger implementation

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_VerifyLeafNodes 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON  ConnectedNodes
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  children NUMBER;
  n1 NUMBER(16,0) := :NEW.node1;
  n2 NUMBER(16,0) := :NEW.node2;
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO children
  FROM Tree
  WHERE parentID = n1 OR parentID = n2;

  IF(children > 0)
  THEN
    RETURN;
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Trigger yet to be implemented');
  END IF;

END
```

Please let me know if the above trigger serves the purpose or not.

Comment: Have you tried running it? If so, what happened? Does it work for all scenarios or does not work? Do you get any errors? StackOverflow isn't a site for code review.Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. That's the most bizarre definition of tree i've ever seen :)
2. No, your trigger is not enough.

a) I assume that if you connect two nodes, when at least one of them is NOT the leaf node, then you want to raise error, not just "return;" out from the trigger

b) To keep your tree consistent with your definition, you must also implement a trigger, that will not allow you to insert any new node, if a parent of such node is 'connected' to other node.

Just from curiosity: what do you need such 'tree' for?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have an assignment where we are modelling entities as nodes. Only entities at leaf nodes are related

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the effect of the above trigger? I believe it should restrict any attempt to enter non leaf nodes in the connected table without giving any warning.

Comment: Your trigger will do exactly nothing.
You do not restrict anything, you just say "return;", which, in that context means "finish the trigger".
If you want to restrict inserts/updates, you **have to** raise exception - caller should know, that the operation has failed and should proceed accordingly.